# If $[L:F]$ is prime, show that either $M\supseteq L$ or $M\cap L=F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E\supseteq L \supseteq  F$ and $E \supseteq  M \supseteq  F$ be fields. If $[L:F]$ is prime, show that either $M\supseteq L$ or $M\cap L=F$.

So I know $E$ is an extension of $L$ and so on. If I assume $[L:F]$ is prime then... Do I have to show that every element in $L$ is in $M$ and if it is not then $M\cap L=F$. I know that $E,L,$ and $M$ are vector spaces. So their elements are vectors, but I'm not sure how to show the double containment.

Comment: $[M\cap L:F]$ divides $[L:F]=p$, so it is either $p$ or $1$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M \cap L$ is a field between $F$ and $L$, and since $[L : F]$ is prime, $M \cap L$ has to be either $F$ or $L$.  But saying $M \cap L = L$ is the same thing as saying $L \subseteq M$.